# PHP script behaves differently in browser

Tags: php, html, hosting, echo

I am trying to list the current USD price of an item in mBTC (millibitcoin) using the Coinbase API. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $string = file_get_contents('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate');
    $result = json_decode($string);
    $spot = $result->amount;
    $price = 2; //change this to your USD value
    $whole = substr($price/$spot, 4, -13);
    $dec = substr($price/$spot, 4, -12);
    echo $whole.'.'.$dec.' mBTC';
?>
```

It works flawlessly in Coderunner (OS X app for development) but fails when run on my hosting server. Link to browser script: http://bitcoindecals.com/oval-price.php

I am using Dynadot Advanced hosting and it includes PHP support. I know that PHP is being utilized because "mBTC" is being echoed correctly. It just appears the `$whole` and `$dec` variables aren't being set for some reason. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Are you getting anything back from your call to the API? Is it decoding properly?

Comment: Yes, I can echo `$spot` and it will give me the full value. It still appears the `$whole` and `$dec` variables are messing up somehow on this server. I just tried using the same script on a different server and works exactly as it does in Coderunner without any changes.

Comment: If `$string` is not filled correctly (which appears to be the cause), then most likely the url wrapper for the `file_get_contents()` function is _not_ enabled in that php configuration. So it allows to read only local files (files on the server itself). Check that, if that is the case you have to implement a different strategy to fetch the remote data. Easiest is using the `curl` php extension.

Comment: I'm able to use `file_get_contents` on this server with no issue. I'm able to get the output of `echo $spot;` with no problem. Things get weird with `$whole` and `$dec`.

Comment: if you didn't get int value for `$price/$spot` , `$price/$spot` it wont get correct results. So I might guess you need to cast the `$spot` value to int.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. EDIT: `$spot = intval($result->amount);` didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a few (extremly wrong) assumptions in the following lines:

```
$whole = substr($price/$spot, 4, -13);
$dec = substr($price/$spot, 4, -12);
```

`$price / $spot` is treated as a string and you assume it will be in the format

```
'0.0019XXXXXXXXXXXX' // 12 x's (unkown numbers)
```

What if Bitcoin is doing really bad and the rate exeeds 10 mBTC per USD? `$price / $spot` will be something like:

```
'0.0108491827849201'; // (10.8 mBTC)
$whole = substr('0.0108491827849201', 4, -13); // Will be '0'
$dec = substr('0.0108491827849201', 4, -12); // Will be '08'
echo $whole . '.' . $dec . ' mBTC'; // Will echo '0.08 mBTC'
```

What if, due to rounding or accuracy (! this is what you're seeing in your server - most likely because your OSX is 64bit, your server 32bit or vice-versa !), the string-length of `$price / $spot` is less than 18 characters:

```
'0.0019564521431';
$whole = substr('0.0019564521431', 4, -13);
// Meaning: start at position 4, stop at 13 characters counting from the end
// 13 characters from the end is here: '0.0019564521431'
//                                       ^
// so the stop-position is before the start-position, resulting in an empty
// string. Same with $dec.
echo $whole . '.' . $dec . ' mBTC'; 
// Will echo empty-string . '.' . empty-string . ' mBTC': '. mBTC'
```

Long story short: never ever treat numbers as a string (unless you have no other options and you are fully aware of what you are doing). Following code will work, and will give the correct output:

```
echo number_format($price / $spot * 1000, 1);
// multiply by 1000: BTC to milli-BTC
// , 1: One digit after the dot
```

For a full explanation of number_format see: http://php.net/number_format

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything makes so much sense now. I looked over the link you posted and cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can't crawler the data from https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate 
so $string is empty! 

    `do {

        $string = file_get_contents('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate');

    } while (!empty($string)); 

    $result = json_decode($string); 

    $spot = $result->amount; 

    $price = 2; //change this to your USD value 

    if (isset($spot) or $spot == 0) { 

         echo "\$spot is not islet or 0"; 

    } else { 

    $whole = substr($price/$spot, 4, -13);

        $dec = substr($price/$spot, 4, -12); 

        echo $whole.'.'.$dec.' mBTC';

    }`

Comment: But, I can. Read above. I'm able to echo the value of `$spot` with no conflicts. It works. Just for some reason `$whole` and `$dec` aren't displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I just executed the exact code in my WAMP server on windows....
It seemed to work perfectly smooth !!!

OUTPUT : `1.19 mBTC`   Is it what you expect????

I think your server is unable to access web pages, so, your php code variables are going vacant...try XAMP and check out ....

Thanks....

Comment: Yes. And it works that way in Coderunner and on another server. I'm just wondering why it isn't working for this one server...

Comment: For the fourth time, the server can access the API link and I can echo the value of `$spot` with no problem.

Comment: I think your server is unable to access web pages, so, your php code variables are going vacant...try XAMP and check out ....

Comment: For the fifth time, the server can access the API link and I can echo the value of `$spot` with no problem.

Comment: I know it is. I said that in my original post. But it obviously isn't "fine" enough. I need some help with the `$whole` and `$dec` variables. The script fails to echo the values of those two variables on the server I'm running my site on: http://bitcoindecals.com/oval-price.php